# Error in array address in function call

Tags: c

```
int coin_change(int value, int denom[], int n) {                                
  int dp[n + 1], i, j;                                        

  dp[0] = 1;                                                                 
  for (i = 1; i <= value; i++) {                                                
    dp[i] = 0;                                                                
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {                                                   
      if (denom[j] <= i) {                                                      
        dp[i] = dp[i] + dp[i - denom[j]];                                    
      }                                                                         
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             

  printf("%d\n", dp[n]);                                                     
}                                                                               

void test_1() {                                                                 
  int denom[3] = {1, 2, 3};                                                   
  coin_change(4, denom, 3);                                                  
}                                                                               

void test_2() {                                                                 
  int denom[4] = {2, 5, 3, 6};                                                
  coin_change(10, denom, 4);                                                 
}                                                                               

int main() {                                                                    
  test_1();                                                                   
  test_2();                                                                     

  return 0;                                                   
}
```

This is a code example for coin change problem that I wrote. Now the first test case runs fine, but in `test_2()`, the address of the passes array `denom[]` is `0x7fff00000000`, which causes a segfault, and I cannot access the memory contents in gdb for that address.

This is the gdb output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005f1 in coin_change (value=10, denom=0x7fff00000000, n=4) at coinchng.c:10
10        if (denom[j] <= i) {
(gdb) p denom
$1 = (int *) 0x7fff00000000
(gdb) p denom[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff00000000
```

I cannot understand, what exactly happens for test_2(), as both test_1() are test_2() are same(with values changed). Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Inside of `coin_change`, you are indexing `dp[i]` and `i` goes from 1 to `value`. In `test_2()` you are passing `10` for `value`. But your declaration in `coin_change` for `dp` is only for `n+1` elements, which is only 5 (since `n` is passed in as 4). You're overflowing `dp` causing the segfault.

Comment: Welcome to the *real* stack overflow...

Comment: @lurker, you wrote the comment so fast ^_^

Comment: How does your code even compile. coin_change doesnt even return a value!

Comment: @novice - that's undefined behavior, but it would probably still compile, hopefully with a warning.

Comment: @IanAbbott It would not compile in c++, does it compile in C?

Comment: @IanAbbott - got it, strange though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take `test_2()`

In that `value = 10`, so `i` will go from `1 to 10`

```
dp[i - denom[j]]
```

In this, when `i = 10` and `j = 0`, the above will become `dp[8]`, but size of `dp[]` is `5` and the valid indices are `0 to 4`.